# How to scan target/test-classes with archunit or reflections in a multi-module application?

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, reflections, archunit

I am writing a test to check all test names, but it looks for reflection in the wrong places

```
public void namingTestMethodTest(JavaClasses classes) {
        methods().that().areAnnotatedWith(Test.class)
                .should().haveNameNotStartingWith("test")
                .andShould().haveNameEndingWith("Test").check(classes);
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Can you elaborate what you mean by "it looks for reflection in the wrong places"? If you get an error message, make sure to include it (see also [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).)

Comment: If you don't provide details, your issue will be flagged to be closed with [Needs details or clarity](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/417485).